# OIDC - Implementing OAuth2 with IdentityServer3 and Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, openid-connect, identityserver3

Our application is a Spring Boot application and we have gotten a requirement to implement OAuth2 authorization with the IdentityServer3 as the provider.

However, with everything set up properly, we keep getting the error `The client application is not known or is not authorized.` when redirected to the login screen of the SSO system.

Using `postman`, we are able to access the login screen when clicking 'Get  New Access Token'

Using `AdvanceRestClient`, we get the same error as our Spring Boot application.

Checking the log of these 2 tools, i found that on postman, the request will POST to the Access Token URL first, while on both Spring Boot security and the AdvanceRESTClient, it will generate a GET URI to the `authorize` URL.

Example of POSTMAN:

```
POST https://login.xxx.com.my/LoginHost/core/connect/token
```

Example of AdvanceRESTClient first request:

```
GET https://login.xxxx.com.my/LoginHost/core/connect/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=xxx.web&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fauth.advancedrestclient.com%2Foauth-popup.html&scope=openid%20email%20profile&state=XXX
```

This is confusing. Which behaviour is correct? And why is there a difference there?

Hope anyone can help with this. Thanks.

*** UPDATE 1 ***

POSTMAN settings:

[image]

AdvanceRESTClient:

[image]

[image]

Comment: how could we answer, when you havn't posted the full code, showing what flow you are implementing, and how you have implemented the flow. Please read through the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question with the relevant information.

Comment: the question here is not about the code, but rather the implementation of the flow. We found that the `AdvanceRESTClient` flow is similar to what Spring Boot security using, hence the question. Will be posting the configuration used in both tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the console logs of both client, it seems that the issue is caused by the `redirect-url`. After changing the redirect url on AdvancedRestClient to match with postman settings then it works.